# Adding images of different sizes into a listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview to which i add images of different sizes, eg. 123x23, 23,43, and so on..
How do i go on about this problem. I know listview has a tilesize property but that sets the general size of all the tiles
Tried with an imagelist, changing the imagelist imagesize doesnt help either... Heres the code i use to add the images to the listbox

The `imglist` in the code is an imagelist to which all the required images are loaded.

```
Private Sub frm_load_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Form1.ListViewEx1.LargeImageList = imglist

            For i = 0 To imglist.Images.Count - 1
                Dim x = Form1.ListViewEx1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("", i))
                x.Tag = imglist.Images.Keys(i).ToString
            Next

            Form1.lbl_status1.Text = "Image Count: " & Form1.ListViewEx1.Items.Count  
End sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. 
I found this and that works for me: [Click here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b2689388-e856-40e9-b2f3-b29e71895761/displaying-different-image-size-in-a-listview?forum=winformsdesigner)

```
Public Sub LoadImageList(ByVal ImagePath As String, ByVal Key As String)

Dim picImage As Image = Nothing
Dim final_Bitmap As Bitmap = Nothing
Dim org_Image As Bitmap = Nothing

If File.Exists(ImagePath) Then
        picImage = Image.FromFile(ImagePath)
'********************* Drawing the Image in proportion to the imagelist Size Here ****************
        Dim proportion As Integer = 0
        Dim startx As Decimal = 0
        Dim startY As Decimal = 0
        Dim drawwidth As Decimal = 0
        Dim drawheight As Decimal = 0
        org_Image = New Bitmap(picImage)
        final_Bitmap = New Bitmap(ImageList1.ImageSize.Width, ImageList1.ImageSize.Height)
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(final_Bitmap)
        Dim factorscale As Decimal
        factorscale = org_Image.Height / org_Image.Width
        drawwidth = final_Bitmap.Width
        drawheight = final_Bitmap.Width * factorscale
        If drawheight > final_Bitmap.Height Then
                proportion = 1
                factorscale = org_Image.Width / org_Image.Height
                drawheight = final_Bitmap.Height
                drawwidth = final_Bitmap.Height * factorscale
        End If
        startx = 0
        startY = final_Bitmap.Height - drawheight
        gr.DrawImage(org_Image, startx, startY, drawwidth, drawheight)
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Key, final_Bitmap)
        org_Image.Dispose()
        final_Bitmap.Dispose()
'************************** End Loading the Image****************
End If

End Sub
```